# Alternating reads and writes to an SQLite database from within a single process

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I'm using an SQLite database as a substitute for a very large in-memory data structure, so I have a simple single-threaded process repeatedly reading from and writing to the database through a single database connection. (I'm using the SQLite C API directly from within a C++ application.) If I perform a write operation, can I later read that data back in without first performing a COMMIT operation? That is, would it work to execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION" when I open the file, do all of my data processing (interleaving reads and writes), then execute "COMMIT" just before closing the file?

I was hoping that OS-level file buffers would allow for this sort of behaviour (e.g., see ["Are Unix reads and writes to a single file atomically serialized?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200923/are-unix-reads-and-writes-to-a-single-file-atomically-serialized)), or perhaps some sort of internal SQLite buffering would come into play, but couldn't find this addressed specifically anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in sqlite3, can a select succeed within a transaction of insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376773/in-sqlite3-can-a-select-succeed-within-a-transaction-of-insert)

Comment: Hmm, good catch (although I wish the answers provided some sort of reference). I tried searching for "sqlite alternate read write single process" and a few other variations on Google and Stack Overflow before asking, but didn't come across that answer.